# SSAS Cube processing error: Invalid Connection String

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, cube, dimension

I am getting this following error:

"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Invalid connection string attribute".; 01000; TCP Provider: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
; 42000; OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)" returned message "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".; 01000; OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Login timeout expired".; 01000.           0
"

I have checked my Datasource files and they seem to have valid connection strings present and the test connection succeeds.

This happens only when i use a Dimension which has 2 related tables (Parent-child) attributes. I believe it makes an adhoc query to retrieve data using the OpenRowSet function, when i see the openrowset sql query I don't find any connection string information present which is the root cause of the error above.

However i am unsure on why or where do i set the string to be correctly pushed on adhoc query that is generated automatically during processing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried SQL Profiler to see what's happening?

Comment: @Anton this is how the sql looks like:

` FROM [dbo].[Medications] AS [dbo_Medications],
  OPENROWSET
  (
   N'SQLNCLI11.1',
   N'',
    N'

    SELECT 
  DISTINCT
 [KNMPName] AS [dbo_MedicationItemsKNMPName1_0],[KNMP] AS [dbo_MedicationItemsKNMPCode1_1]
  FROM [dbo].[MedicationItems] '
  )
  AS [dbo_MedicationIms]
  WHERE 
  (
   
  (`

Comment: what is the source for your dimension? Named Query?

Comment: @Anton the source is a set of two tables from the data source

Comment: @Anton Profiler cannot help you if the server is not found. Profiler traces existing connections, no connection -> nothing in the trace

Comment: @sepupic, Profiler can be used to trace Login attempts (Audit events)

Comment: @NikhilLaddha Any chance to create a view and use that view as source? It will eliminate usage of OPENROWSET

Comment: @Anton Really? Profiler traces what is reached the server, but if server is not found no connection attempts at all.

Comment: @sepupic Server can be reached, but with wrong credentials or disabled login. In this case Profiler may help. If Profiler does not show login attempts, of course it means server was not reached.

Comment: @Anton We are not talking about "login failed" (when the server is really reached). we are talking about OP's error saying **Server is not found or not accessible**

Comment: @Anton view doesn't look like a good solution because this is only the beginnig and i will have 100 such situations repeated again and i may not be able to create a view for all of them. However your suggestion helps to see different side altogether.

Comment: @sepupic Similar messages can be generated by linked server located on the server, e.g. when SSAS connects the server, runs some query that accesses its linked server with wrong configuration, so in general, when we don't know OP system, it's hard to say where is that message from.

Comment: @Anton, I missed LINKED server, sorry

Comment: OPENROWSET, the Ad Hoc Distributed Queries advanced configuration option is enabled. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql. OPENQUERY uses linked server, do you set it up?

Comment: @Wendy I have the configuration enabled. Thanks for pointing out, any other clues ?

Comment: Please add the server name in your query. You can find a sample in the link I mentioned. Meanwhile change the FROM clause to databasename.schema.tablename.